# Select date before 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to select date before 7 days from end_date in SQL Server

```
select *
from price_monitor
where end_date >= dateadd(d,7,getdate())
```

Comment: what is the issue with that query ?

Comment: Bear in mind htat GETDATE() return the time part. You want to do CAST(DATEADD(DAY,  -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

Answer (score 1):

You have to put as `-7` for before days.

```sql
select * from price_monitor WHERE end_date >=  DATEADD(dd,-7,GETDATE())
```

In my system, it will work as

```sql
select * from price_monitor WHERE end_date >= '2021-02-23 02:25:20.390'
```

Comment: i try it but it's not working
all dates are selected

Comment: @KarimElEssawy what does "not working" mean? Please show sample data, expected results and actual results.

Comment: Are you foolishly storing dates as a `varchar` @KarimElEssawy ...? The first query won't return "all the dates", of that i can assure you.